# How to hide some menus in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

In my app I have nearly 8 menus and I have two types of users admin and client

for Admin I need to show all 8 manus and for user I need to show 2 menus for user

for that I have Given this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_mymenu, menu);
    return true;      
}
```

after my code will be at on resume I am adding below one

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences(my_New_SP, 0);
    HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) s.getAll();

    int id = item.getItemId();

 if (map.get("usage").equals("Admin"))
 {
    if (id == R.id.abc) {
        Intent mypIntent = new Intent(this, Myp.class);
        startActivity(mypIntent);
        return true;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    else if (id == R.id.web1) {
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(this, Web.class);
        startActivity(webIntent);
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.about1) {
        Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(aboutIntent);
        return true;
    }   
}

if (map.get("usage").equals("User"))
{
    if (id == R.id.web1) {
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(this, Web.class);
        startActivity(webIntent);
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.about1) {
        Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(aboutIntent);
        return true;
    }
}   
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

So here In Options Menus I want to Show Only Two for user and 8 for admin..

But when I select it as user I and able to see all menus and only two of them are working.. so here I want to show only working menus remaning should hide..

can any one suggest me of this kind..

Here menus are from android menus only not dynamic menus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onCreateOptionsMenu(), check for the condition and show or hide it the following way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.m_mymenu, menu);


SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences(my_New_SP, 0);
HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) s.getAll();

if (map.get("usage").equals("Admin"))
 {
 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.usermenu1);
 item.setVisible(false); 
 //your all user menu's same like above

}


else if (map.get("usage").equals("User"))
{
 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.adminmenu1);
 item.setVisible(false); 
 //your all admin menu's same like above
}

  return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Ranjhid Kumar sir,   Here I am when I use this in my code i am getting error at item and "menu." please check my updated question where Should I need to change my code

Comment: @Don'tBenegative try the code inside onCreateOptionMenu().. see my edited answer..

Comment: sir please see my update question sir... If I follow you code I am getting error... Here I am using map.get("usage").equals("User") from shared prefs.. at on resume

Comment: @Don'tBenegative tell the line of error.. & error details..check my updated answer

Comment: Yes sir I am using shared prefs at on resume means at menusitem part in my question... in my code menu is separate and menus item is separate..

Comment: @Don'tBenegative see my updated answer.. you not tell me which line you got error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108156/discussion-between-ranjith-kumar-and-dont-be-negative).

Answer (score 0):

```
private Menu menu1;
```

now in oncreate do something like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        menu1 = menu.findItem(R.id.web1);
        menu1.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
```

now you can hide/show `menu1` where ever you want. do same for the other options